# Mudar a cor de um input depois do usuário digitar X caracteres com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde,
estou tentando fazer um input, onde o usuário digita um texto. O que quero fazer é:
Depois que o usuário digitar 100 caracteres, os próximos caracteres que ele digitar vão ficar com outra cor.
Alguém saber como posso fazer?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" maxlength="255">

  <script>
    let input = document.querySelector("input");

    input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
      if(input.value.length > 10) {
      console.log(input.value.substring(10));
      }
    })
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Segue um código de exemplo, eu quero pegar esse texto depois do usuário digitar 10 caracteres e mudar a cor dele.

Comment: Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar a sua tentativa junto com uma descrição do resultado que obteve?

Comment: editei @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411268/5878